# xcopy to a password protected network location

Tags: batch-file, dos, xcopy

I've recently taken over an IT position at my company. I'm trying to set up automated daily backups of the computers user accounts. I've gotten the .bat file running fine, and it works fine IF I've already connected to the backup server via windows explorer.

What I mean is this, if I go to explorer, then type in manually `\\server-name\folder$\username` it will prompt user and password, I'll enter that and connect just fine.

However if they reboot, they lose access unless they re-enter the password. So, can I script xcopy to include the password in the command line, or is there another way to backup to a network password protected dir?

Comment: Can't edit, server path should have included another slash in the beginning, it edited it out.

     \\server-name\folder$\username

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go to Explorer you can map the path `\\server-name\folder$\username` to a letter drive, e.g. "N:". While you map there's an option "Reconnect at Logon". This way every time user reboots and logins - connection to network share will be automatically reestablished.

Comment: Great. I'll try this on a computer, and report back. Thank you @Trekstuff

Comment: No problem :) Please mark the response as Answer if it worked for you. Please let me know if you have any questions/problems with that approach.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered. I will have to wait until tomorrow to see if it worked though, but I've implemented the suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work though for scheduled scripts and no logged-in user, does it.